# Folium get location and zoom level

Tags: python, get, location, zooming, folium

I'd like to find the current view location of a folium map, and the current zoom level.

I created a map object

```
>> self.map1 = folium.Map(
            tiles='Stamen Terrain',
            zoom_start=zoom0,
            location=coordinate
        )
```

After a user interacted with it, I'd like to know the current viewed coordinate & zoom level. (in this case to save and recall at the next startup)

```
>> print(self.map1.getLocation())
>> print(self.map1.getZoom())
```

yielding

```
AttributeError: 'Map' object has no attribute 'getLocation'
AttributeError: 'Map' object has no attribute 'getZoom'
```

I believe folium uses leaflet, which has a getZoom() method itself according to:
https://leafletjs.com/reference.html#Map

How can one access these parameters in folium/python?

Comment: `folium` generates HTML with JavaScript and it sends it to browser which displays it and which you can zoom and move - and you would have to add JavaScript code which gets current location and zoom, and later sends it back to Python on server.

Answer (score 2):

In folium there is an **alternative ways** that I know of, to get **position** by using `plugins`.

```
import folium
from folium import plugins
    
m = folium.Map(location = [13.8041258,100.4481389],zoom_start = 12 )
```

The first method is use `MousePosition plugin` to get position by **mouse position**.

```
roundnum = "function(num) {return L.Util.formatNum(num, 5);};"
plugins.MousePosition(position='topright', separator=' | ', prefix="Position:",lat_formatter=roundnum, lng_formatter=roundnum).add_to(m)
m
```

The second is use `Draw plugin` to put a **mark** on the map and click on it, to see the position.

```
plugins.Draw(export=False, position='topleft', draw_options=None, edit_options=None).add_to(m)  
m
```

Unfortunately, I don't know how to get zoom level.
Hope this helps

Comment: I think it is possible to inject html into python folium maps, and use javascript to `var mapZoom = {m}.getZoom();` . but I lack the knowledge to complete it.

Comment: However interesting, this does still not give the location of the current view. 
You gave the input of the location to be [13.8041258,100.4481389], which is the centre of the window. 
I was looking to get this number, after a user dragged the position of the view in the UI

Answer (score 0):

There is no such function in the Folium library. From my own experience I would recommend using the leafletjs library to benefit from more options because I faced the same issues as you in Folium.

Comment: Do you mean by injecting javascript as @Reoun suggested? (as leaflet itself is made in javascript, right?)

Comment: yes, or switching completely to javascript.